# Can anyone point to the cause of this error in tomcat localhost log?

Tags: java, tomcat, localhost

```
11-Apr-2013 12:56:04 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:751)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:781)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:710)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:304)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContentAsUtf8(RPCServletUtils.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.genesyslabs.wfm70.server.filters.RPCRequestCharsetFilter.doFilter(RPCRequestCharsetFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.genesyslabs.wfm70.server.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Not until you post some and some information about your environment.

Comment: As you can probably see I'm very fresh to this - what environment info would help here? :)

Comment: Technologies and frameworks you use for example. Also some code would be nice

Comment: Why did you tag this "localhost" ?

Comment: it's in the localhost log in the tomcat directory

Comment: when exactly do you get this connection reset? Provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

What it seems to be saying is that the other end (in this case a GWT client) has closed the connection unexpectedly.  I don't think there's much more we can deduce from the stack trace.  You will need to provide more information about the technologies, what your system does, and the circumstances in which this failure occurs.

(One possible explanation is that the user closed his / her browser at just the wrong instant ...)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Our environment serves a call centre management application - there are two load-balanced tomcat webservers that connect to various reporting servers, with approximately 200 simultaneous users. Users of the application saw heavy slowdown on the 12th April, the only thing that looks out of the ordinary in the tomcat logs is the above entry from the 11th.

Comment: @user2199693 - Well, I would say that that exception is unlikely to tell you the cause of the slowdown.  Did you look in the system logs?  The database logs?

Answer (score 0):

Which java version do you use?
It looks like a java 7 bug, which causes troubles with windows firewall.
[bug #7077696](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696)

Comment: This answer is nonsense.  The bug report is for FTP, and this is definitely not FTP.  That much is obvious from the stack trace.